# Responsive 2 column to 1 column email in Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013

Tags: html, mobile, outlook, html-email

I'm working on optimizing HTML emails for mobile devices. I have been tasked with finding a universal solution for creating a 2 column to 1 column responsive layout. I found an article written by Campaign Monitor - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/responsive/. I've tried their markup and it works on most clients and browsers with the exception of Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013. I've provided a jsfiddle link with my markup for reference. Is there a way to make this work in these version of Outlook?

EDIT: I'm not trying to make the responsive part of the email work in Outlook. I want the 2 tables ( Left & Right in the jsfiddle example) to display next to each other rather than stacked on top of one another. This works in Gmail (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari), AOL (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari), Yahoo (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari), Hotmail (IE, FF, Chrome, Safari), Apple Mail 4 & 5, Outlook 2003, Android 4.0, iOS 4, 5, & 6. My concern is only with Outlook 2007 and later when the rendering engine changed.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    @media all and (max-width: 590px){
      *[class].responsive{ width: 320px !important; }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%" style="background-color: #000;" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td height="15"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%">
          <table width="560" style="background-color: #fff;" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsive">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="100%">
                  <table width="280" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsive">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" height="40" style="background-color: #ececec;">
                          <div height="40" style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif; text-align:center;">Left (top)</div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table width="280" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsive">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" height="40" style="background-color: #bcbcbc;">
                          <div height="40" style="font-weight:bold; font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif; text-align:center;">Right (bottom)</div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="15"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxdUp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding `align="left"` and `align="right"` to the stacking tables?

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxdUp/1/

You currently have the right table with `align="left"`, but I have had success with Outlook table alignment manipulating the `align` value.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet. I'll test it now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add to that, you *may* also need to set the `border` attribute to `0` on your inner tables - it *shouldn't* matter, but I've seen weirder things.

Comment: That unfortunately does not seem to work in outlook 2007 and 2010 (see screenshots of litmus tests here: [outlook 2007](http://i.imgur.com/iPCtB.png) and [outlook 2010](http://i.imgur.com/9MeOb.png))

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that comes across this SO and is looking for a solution to the above problem where the responsive 2-column content is ALSO centered I found that using conditionals to define columns only for Outlook made my world 1^300 easier.  Of course it is no longer responsive in Outlook, but really... F Outlook.

```
<!-- define a 100% width table -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td width="100%" style="text-align:center; background-color:white">

    <!-- define a fixed width table using a class for responsive.  I found that defining an arbitary height seemed to be important ~ silly Outlook -->
    <!-- align center -->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fixedWidthTable" border="0" height="300" align="center">
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>

          <!-- align left (this renders as float:left in webkit).  Absolutely defined width. -->
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" align="left" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:300px">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- content -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

    <!-- > THIS BIT IS THE KICKER < whack in a column if Outlook -->
    <!--[if mso]></td><td><![endif]-->
    <!-- Brilliant. -->

          <!-- align right (this renders as float:right in webkit).  Absolutely defined width. -->
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="300" align="right" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:300px">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- content -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    ... close outer tables etc.
```

Comment: Genius, was just thinking this would be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that reductions in table widths by a few pixels work in the case for Outlook, which I can only assume is Outlook rendering pixel widths differently than other email clients.

Not ideal, but it has worked for me.

Comment: I believe the reason is that outlook inserts a small space after each table, not that the tables them selves are sized differently. Making them slightly smaller works as a fix though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is gonna work on Outlook versions. Because first of all Outlook doesn't understand media queries. Outlook version 2007 is based on the rendering Engine of IE, while as Outlook version 2010 and version 2013 use Word as the rendering engine for displaying html emails. So I believe there is no way to get them to work in Outlook.

One more point is that when this code is executed in Outlook, it will ignore everything that is inside style tags. You should give style as inline for Outlook emails.

Comment: I understand Outlook doesn't recognize media queries but those media queries are only relevant for mobile devices. If you look at the jsfiddle example you'll see that if you expand the html output container the two tables are aligned left and next to each other. Outlook stacks the tables on top of each other instead of displaying them next to each other.

Comment: Actually, it is Outlook 2003 that last used IE - 2007+ all use Word.  Also, [Outlook supports `style` tags](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) (almost every major email client does, Gmail being the sole exception).